# Get values of a failed test in Maven Surefire Plugin

Tags: java, maven, unit-testing, maven-surefire-plugin

I'm used to working with boost test that, when a test fails it shows the two values in which is comparing for example:

```
test": check 0.99999608 == discountFactor1.getDiscountFactor() has failed [0.99999607999999995 != 0.99999608334867351].
```

Now In Java, I'm using Maven Surefire, and when a test fails it tells the position of the code where is the invocation of the test like for example:

```
java.lang.AssertionError
...
testSendRequest(sendRequestTest.java:295)
```

In this position I have the invocation of a test:

```
295 Assert.assertTrue(HHH.getSequenceNumber() == sequenceNumber);
```

Is there any way to know the values of HHH.getSequenceNumber() and sequenceNumber if the test fails?

Answer (score 1):

The actual message is probably provided by your IDE that goes beyond the unit test framework features :

> test": check 0.99999608 == discountFactor1.getDiscountFactor() has
>   failed [0.99999607999999995 != 0.99999608334867351].

To achieve a similarly thing with Maven, you could use the overloaded `assertTrue()` method that adds in the output a textual message associated to the failure :

```
Assert.assertTrue(String msg, boolean condition)
```

You could write that :

```
Assert.assertTrue(HHH.getSequenceNumber() + " is not equals to " + 
                 sequenceNumber, 
                 HHH.getSequenceNumber() == sequenceNumber);
```

But in fact I think that you should use `Assert.assertEquals()` that in case of failing test provides a message comparing the two objects.
You could so write :

```
Assert.assertEquals(HHH.getSequenceNumber(), sequenceNumber);
```